# Configure unmanaged k8s Load Balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes

In the docs about [Load Balancer Service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) it says that

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your Service.

I'm trying to understand - if I manually install a Kubernetes cluster on a set of VMs in Azure for example, and create a `LoadBalancer` service, does kubernetes somehow provisions a Azure Load Balancer for me? That doesn't sound so reasonable - it must have a lot of data to do that - subscription, resource group, credentials.

The docs don't really explain this... is it only possible on managed Kubernetes clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you installed an unmanaged cluster on a cloud provider, you need to install a resource called [cloud controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/).

basically, the cloud controller connects the Kubernetes resources to the cloud provider and helps you create resources on your cloud, based on the kubernetes configuration, resources like disks, and LoadBalancers.

in your case, you can look at the [cloud-provider-azure](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cloud-provider-azure) repo.